# A failure occurred attempting to install the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile

Tags: c#, visual-studio, frameworks, installation, publish

I wrote an application in VS2015. I had to change the project properties to Framework 4 client profile since one of the customer has WinXP SP3. According to Microsoft, it is fine.
I have created a setup file from the publish tab in the project properties.
I checked in Prerequisites:

1. Component Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64) and Update for .NET Framework 4 (KB2468871)
2. Window Installer 4.5

I select "Download prerequisites from the component vendor's website".
I clicked on Publish and I get the setup file and all its dependencies.

I ran the setup file on the Window XP OS, it took a lot of time to install the .Net Framework and once finished, I got the following message:

```
Component Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64) and Update
for .NET Framework 4 (KB2468871) has failed to install with the following 
error message:
"A failure occurred attempting to install the .NET Framework 4 Client 
Profile."

The following components failed to install:
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64) and Update for   
.NET Framework 4 (KB2468871)

See the setup log file located at 
'C:\DOCUME~1\eric_h\LOCALS~1\Temp\VSD9.tmp\install.log' for more information.
```

I am not clear what is wrong, please advise.

Comment: Is the target PC, member of a network?

Comment: If I understood your question, yes we are working on a same network.

Comment: Check this address in the target PC registry and see if the value is `c9` :`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WinTrust\Trust Providers\Software Publishing\State`

Comment: Ok.Then I have no more ideas. sorry.